# How to split a string(extract words) without stringstream and strtok in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How to split a string(extract words) without `stringstream` and `strtok` in C++?

I want to split a string that has multiple consecutive spaces between each word, and it may span multiple lines as well have white space before a new line start.

So far I have this but it can only handle one space

```
while (input.compare(word) != 0)
{
   index = input.find_first_of(" ");
   word = input.substr(0,index);
   names.push_back(word);
   input = input.substr(index+1, input.length());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: *How to split a string(extract words) without stringstream and strtok in C++* -- Use `boost::algorithm::split`.  Also, why don't you want to use `stringstream`?

Comment: just don't push_back if word is empty

Comment: For example like [this](https://github.com/crusader-mike/parray). See example at "Split string and process every part without mem alloc". Just use _split_se()_ instead of _split()_

Comment: @codekaizer Thank you for the link but all the codes there use libraries that I don't want.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie just a requirement I have and i can't use that either.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference:

```
std::string input = "   hello   world   hello    "; // multiple spaces
std::string word = "";
std::vector<std::string> names;

while (input.compare(word) != 0)
{
   auto index = input.find_first_of(" ");
   word = input.substr(0,index);

   input = input.substr(index+1, input.length());

   if (word.length() == 0) {
      // skip space
      continue;
   }

   // Add non-space word to vector
   names.push_back(word);
}
```

Check in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/79ieyW7P2eq2jB9S)

Comment: Hi @Yakk, agreed for `substr`. is there an elegant way to prevent copy?

Comment: use string view (C++17) or write your own.  You use `==`, `find_first_of`, `substr` and convert to std::string; so not that hard.

Comment: Why just not use `find_first_not_of` to skip delimiter and than `find_first_of` to find delimiter and in between you have your toke.

Comment: @JobNick, for OP to easily differentiate what's missing.